# Is it possible to update Ruby version in RPG Maker XP

Tags: ruby, unicode, game-engine

This is related with unicode support. The current RPG Maker ruby version is 1.8, The problem is, using english RPG Maker, one cannot display non-standard character such as kanji (japanese characters) inside game's message window. The text was stored properly in a variable but messed up when being shown on game's message to display text. It is shown properly on console. The result was the text shown blank or in form of random boxes. I have made sure my system locale set to japanese

Then I played a japanese game made with RPG Maker, it works fine, I can see those kanji. But then I try to edit them using my english RPG Maker XP, save them, play it again, the game run without error but the text are all gone (invisible). I tried multiple experiments on this, including changing the font, unicode of where the text was stored, .dll being used, RTP Version, none of them serve as solution.

In short, in order to display japanese text properly, I have to use Japanese RPG Maker XP. I already own an english RPG Maker and I want to distribute my game in japanese language. And this unicode problem lead me to a dead end, there is no point if my RPG Maker cannot display japanese characters.

Why ? we have an exactly same software to create a game, only different language but why I cannot see the text ? I have English RPG Maker VX (newer version than XP, built in newer version of ruby) and it has no such problem. But I don't want to use VX nor VX Ace.

This localization problem was just one of reason I ask : is there any possible way, to update the ruby used in RPG Maker which only provide partial unicode support ?

Comment: It might not be related to the version of Ruby. If whatever graphics renderer the English RPG Maker uses doesn't support kanji characters, it won't make a difference.

Comment: I was think so too, the original version, japanese RPG Maker XP handle it properly. If english version was only change its UI languange, then it should be no problem. I have tried to do experiments with this graphic renderer by changing the font with unicode support, etc. There is a limit we can do in modifying RPG Maker, unlike common game libraries, the core libraries mostly handle most basic method cannot be edited. So for not be confusing, I will change my question. Is there any way to display japanese character in in-game message window using english version of RPG Maker XP ?

Comment: Oh!, the update from RTP ver 1.03 fix this, I'll just need to use RGSS103J.dll library, set my locale to japanese, and I can cheat this unicode problem. Well this solved my problem. Back to the main topic, regardless the unicode things, is there is any way to update ruby version

Comment: I'm not that familiar with RPG Maker XP, but my hunch is that you can't. The Ruby interpreter is probably compiled into the application, so the only way to upgrade it would be to have access to the RPG Maker source code.

Answer (score 2):

The Characters won't show up in-game if the Font used does not support Kanji Characters. ***The default Font in the English Does Not Work with Kanji!***. Set the font to one that supports the characters (i used a script to set the font) and you or Anyone playing wont have to change their local. font must be installed on your system AND in the Fonts folder of the game to work.